# Synchronizing two video decoders with ffmpeg/libavcodec

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, libavcodec, libav

I have two video streams encoded with the same frame rate. I'm trying to display the decoded frames from the two streams synchronously. The two streams are not within the same container. Using ffmpeg/libavcodec I created two decoders and I have no problems with the decoding process. The decoders are running in separate threads. I would like the output frame from one decoder to wait for the corresponding frame in the other decoder before being rendered.

Any help is greatly appreciated.